# Challenge in data from REST API using Azure Data Factory - access issue

Tags: rest, networking, azure-data-factory

We are trying to reach to an API hosted in our company network using rest connector in ADF (SHIR is used). Linked service connection is successful but dataset is unable to read the data and copy activity is as well failing with below error. Please suggest your thoughts in resolving the same.

> Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailToReadFromRestResource,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred while sending the request.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,Message=An error occurred while sending the request.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=Unable to connect to the remote server,Source=System,''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ,Source=System,'

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly seen due to firewall issues. You might want to verify your network firewall setting to allow the API request to be read.

Also, verify if your API call is working as expected using other API testing tools. If the issue persists you can raise a support ticket for engineers to investigate more on the issue.